# how to reverse records in pl/sql

Tags: plsql

how to reverse records in pl/sql

Comment: Your question is too brief to be intelligible to other people.  Please give us more to go on.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`ORDER BY`](http://psoug.org/reference/orderby.html) clause with either `ASCENDING` or `DESCENDING` when selecting your records.